# If file exists then continue

Tags: fortran

I want to check whether a file exists so that I can load it in to my program. In general my files are named as 010, 020, 030 and so on, but depending on a specific case, sometimes some of them are missing resulting in first file named f.e. 030.

I have a function that changes the name of a loading file if such file exists, but if it does not, the program terminates. I want to have a function that checks if such file exists, if not then change the name as

```
name=000
do
 if (file exists) continue
 if (file doesnt exist) then
 name = name + 10
end do
```

and proceed with my calculations on this file.

Does anyone have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: The answer to the linked question contains a suitable function.  That question seems to be about making an _operator_, but sufficient information is available there regarding inquire-by-file (using `inquire`) for progress in this problem.

Comment: There are a number of problems I see with the question. 1) Is the file related to data for your program or in the linker when you are building your program? 2) If in the program, you have not used Fortran syntax. Surely an IF ... THEN ... ELSE structure would solve your problem. 3) "name = name + 10" needs more work as you need to convert name into file_name using valid Fortran syntax.